# Time series data: Extract, store and write data to csv in c#

Tags: c#

I have 50k features. and each feature has data points with its time stamps. I need to extract the data from database and write it to csv. For output csv is expected to be as in the picture, there's time stamp beside every data points.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkmZG.png)

I'm still very new to c# but I wonder, if there's a way I can store the data in key value /library with its title n write it to csv.

example:

```
title: feature 1
key: 18.5 value: 2/1/2017
key: 18.5 value: 2/1/2017
key: 18.5 value: 2/1/2017
```

and since, the data size is very big, I have problem with the total execution time. it takes around 15 minutes to extract 5 minutes data. I wish to reduce the running time.

Comment: If you have code that you're already using then please show us that. If you don't, then write the code and show us that.

Comment: Yeah a minimum reproducible example is a requirement for code troubleshooting posts.